# Sending mail with PHP using sendgrid fails due to mistake in JSON

Tags: php, sendgrid

I'm following the example here:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/mail/mail.php

I've stripped the majority of parameters to send a very basic email:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // If you're using Composer (recommended)
$apiKey = getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$request_body = json_decode('{
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text/html", 
      "value": "<html><p>Hello, world!</p></html>"
    }
  ], 
  "from": {
    "email": "alice@domain.com",
    "name": "Sender Alice"
  }, 
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "bob@domain.com", 
          "name": "Receiver Bob"
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
}');

try {
    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($request_body);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

When executed I get the following error

> `{"errors":[{"message":"Content-Type should be application/json.","field":null,"help":null}]}`

Looking at the original example, I don't see anything that I might have removed that would cause this, although I'm probably wrong.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the last `,` in your request_body variable.

Change

```
"personalizations": [
{
  "to": [
    {
      "email": "bob@domain.com", 
      "name": "Receiver Bob"
    }
  ]
}],
```

To this

```
"personalizations": [
{
  "to": [
    {
      "email": "bob@domain.com", 
      "name": "Receiver Bob"
    }
  ]
}]
```

When I run into these problems I run my json against a validator. A lot of times it'll give me an idea of where to start.

https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: What a rookie mistake. Thanks for finding it and for the tip.

Comment: @equinoxe5 No problem! Glad it helped.